# Best Data Structure for Genetic Algorithm in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

i need to implement a genetic algorithm customized for my problem (college project), and the first version had it coded as an matrix of short ( bits per chromosome x size of population).

That was a bad design, since i am declaring a short but only using the "0" and "1" values... but it was just a prototype and it worked as intended, and now it is time for me to develop a new, improved version. Performance is important here, but simplicity is also appreciated.

I researched around and came up with:

for the chromosome :
- String class (like "0100100010")
- Array of bool
- Vector (vectors appears to be optimized for bool)
- Bitset (sounds the most natural one)

and for the population:
- C Array[]
- Vector
- Queue

I am inclined to pick vector for chromossome and array for pop, but i would like the opinion of anyone with experience on the subject.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you want random access to the population and to the genes.  You say performance is important, which I interpret as execution speed.  So you're probably best off using a `vector<>` for the chromosomes and a `vector<char>` for the genes.  The reason for `vector<char>` is that `bitset<>` and `vector<bool>` are optimized for memory consumption, and are therefore slow.  `vector<char>` will give you higher speed at the cost of x8 memory (assuming `char` = byte on your system).  So if you want speed, go with `vector<char>`.  If memory consumption is paramount, then use `vector<bool>` or `bitset<>`.  `bitset<>` would seem like a natural choice here, however, bear in mind that it is templated on the number of bits, which means that a) the number of genes must be fixed and known at compile time (which I would guess is a big no-no), and b) if you use different sizes, you end up with one copy per `bitset` size of each of the `bitset` methods you use (though inlining might negate this), i.e., code bloat.  Overall, I would guess `vector<bool>` is better for you if you don't want `vector<char>`.

If you're concerned about the aesthetics of `vector<char>` you could `typedef char gene;` and then use `vector<gene>`, which looks more natural.

A `string` is just like a `vector<char>` but more cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to answer your question. I am not exactly sure what you are suggestion. You talk about Array and string class. Are you talking about the STL container classes where you can have a queue, bitset, vector, linked list etc. I would suggest a vector for you population (closest thing to a C array there is) and a bitset for you chromosome if you are worried about memory capacity. Else as you are already using a vector of your string representaion of your dna. ("10110110")

For ideas and a good tool to dabble. Recommend you download and initially use this library. It works with the major compilers. Works on unix variants. Has all the source code.

All the framework stuff is done for you and you will learn a lot. Later on you could write your own code from scratch or inherit from these classes. You can also use them in commercial code if you want.

Because they are objects you can change representaion of your DNA easily from integers to reals to structures to trees to bit arrays etc etc.

There is always learning cure involved but it is worth it.

I use it to generate thousands of neural nets then weed them out with a simple fitness function then run them for real.

galib

http://lancet.mit.edu/ga/

Comment: Look interesting. I however will stick with the devil I know for now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to code this yourself (if you want an external library kingchris seems to have a good one there) it really depends on what kind of manipulation you need to do. To get the most bang for your buck in terms of memory, you could use any integer type and set/manipulate individual bits via bitmasks etc. Now this approach likely not optimal in terms of ease of use... The string example above would work ok, however again its not significantly different than the shorts, here you are now just representing either '0' or '1' with an 8 bit value as opposed to 16 bit value. Also, again depending on the manipulation, the string case will probably prove unwieldly. So if you could give some more info on the algorithm we could maybe give more feedback. Myself I like the individual bits as part of an integer (a bitset), but if you aren't used to masks, shifts, and all that good stuff it may not be right for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a class for each member of population, that simplifies things considerably, since you can keep all your member relevant functions in the same place nicely wrapped with the actual data.

If you need a "array of bools" I suggest using an int or several ints (then use mask and bit wise operations to access (modify / flip) each bit) depending on number of your chromosomes.

I usually used some sort of collection class for the population, because just an array of population members doesn't allow you to simply add to your population. I would suggest implementing some sort of dynamic list (if you are familiar with ArrayList then that is a good example).

I had major success with genetic algorithms with the recipe above. If you prepare your member class properly it can really simplify things and allows you to focus on coding better genetic algorithms instead of worrying about your data structures.